# How to declare DATALINK type? FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to use DATALINK type for a field in my database. 
Could somebody write step by step how to do this?

I've declared:

```
CREATE TABLE casting_test
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  url datalink
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

and got error that no such a datatype existst. SQL state: 42704.

What to do first?

Comment: There is no data type named *datalink*. What do you think that would be or should do?

Comment: I've found it in Peter Eisentraut's presentation  http://www.pgcon.org/2009/schedule/attachments/133_pgcon2009-sqlmed.pdf - It's part of SQL/MED which is extension to the SQL standard.

Comment: You should read the manual rather than presentations referring to planned new features.

Comment: from http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL/MED: "Current Status

The implementation of this specification began in PostgreSQL 8.4 and will over time introduce powerful new features into PostgreSQL." So it was worth checking out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL [does not support DATALINK](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/unsupported-features-sql-standard.html).

Comment: Thank you. Maybe is there some other way to get equivalent functionality?

Comment: What `DATALINK` functionality do you need? Can't you use `VARCHAR` fields to store URLs, and work with them directly? As far as I could find, IBM DB2 is the only major DBMS that supports `DATALINK`, and I'm not familiar with DB2, so I have no idea what functionality is available with that type.

Comment: I do use varchar, but e.g. FILE LINK CONTROL seemed to be really interesting. If I have good understood the aim of this statement.

Comment: I don't think any of the link control semantics can be implemented in Postgres. You'll need to handle them on the application side.